"Failed to execute skript 'pyiboot01_bootstrap' due to unhandled exception: Bootloader did not set sys._pyinstaller_pyz!"
I have a Python skript (but what is inside is not important in the case), which I pack into an executable file. I used to have no problems with it before, but yesterday I faced some. This is how I used to build it.
PS C:\Users\Documents\guacamole> pyinstaller -F `
>> --distpath="C:\Users\Documents\Executables" `
>> --workpath="C:\Users\Documents\Executables" `
>> --specpath="C:\Users\Documents\Executables" `
>> --add-data="C:\Users\Documents\guacamole\Genesis_Tool\data\logo.png;Genesis_Tool\data" `
>> --add-data="C:\Users\Documents\guacamole\Genesis_Tool\data\Anleitungen.pdf;Genesis_Tool\data" `
>> --add-data="C:\Users\Documents\guacamole\Genesis_Tool\data\config.json;Genesis_Tool\data" `
>> --paths="C:\Users\Documents\guacamole\venv\Lib\site-packages" `
>> --paths="C:\Users\Documents\guacamole\Modules" `
>> --noconsole Genesis_Tool\src\main.py

But today, I faced the error:
 Failed to execute skript 'pyiboot01_bootstrap' due to unhandled exception: Bootloader did not set sys._pyinstaller_pyz!

It was also telling me:
Python environment: C:\Users\z004zfmr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312
300 INFO: wrote C:\Users\z004zfmr\Documents\Executables\main.spec
300 DEPRECATION: Foreign Python environment's site-packages paths added to --paths/pathex:
['C:\\Users\\z004zfmr\\Documents\\guacamole\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages']

This is ALWAYS the wrong thing to do. If your environment's site-packages is not in PyInstaller's module search path then you are running PyInstaller from a different environment to the one your packages are in. Run print(sys.prefix) without PyInstaller to get the environment you should be using then install and run PyInstaller from that environment instead of this one. This warning will become an error in PyInstaller 7.0.
So I had to activate venv and build then.
After activating venv and building like this, which I never had to do before, I could open my executable file and it was running good, until I copied and pasted it in another folder. I always do this and there has never been a problem, but now, after it has been copied to another folder, I have to wait 2-3 minutes until it's opened. The problem is not in the code, more like something in the paths, but I can't find a solution. The only thing that I could think of, is a problem I had in my code a couple of weeks ago. The function used to be like this:
def path_Resource(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """    
    base_path = None  # Initialize base_path
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        if hasattr(sys, "_MEIPASS"):
            # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
            base_path = sys._MEIPASS
            logging.info("Resource base path is MEIPASS")
            # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
            base_path = sys._MEIPASS
            logging.info("Resource base path is MEIPASS")
    except Exception:
        pass
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

And it never caused problems. But one day, i had a following error:
Script Start
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Documents\guacamole\Genesis_Tool\src\main.py", line 27, in <module>  
    LOGO = os_Tools.path_Resource(r"Genesis_Tool\data\logo.png")
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Documents\guacamole\Modules\os_Tools.py", line 122, in path_Resource 
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen ntpath>", line 108, in join
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

I added this to the end of the code:
if base_path is None:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")
        logging.info("Resource base path is abspath")

And there was no problem. This is the only thing that I can think of. Does someone have assumptions?
